# Contacts are not fetched properly in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-contacts

Is there anybody facing the same problem what I am facing now? My application retrieves all the contacts list (including their emails and phone numbers) and sends those to server. It was working fine until 4.4. But failed for some account (Live or Exchange Account) from Lollipop.

To check it I have downloaded the sample app provided by Google from the below link:

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

This app also behaved the same. Now I don't know how should I solve the problem as Google's official app fails to retrieve the proper contacts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain completely and precisely what "failed for some account" means.

Comment: If you configured an Exchange account in your Email app. All the contacts from your Exchange server will show in Contacts App. All those contacts are not fetched in the app provided in the mentioned link. I mean both native contact app and the app from the link shows different list of contacts.